# Random-walk prior with ridge-like regularizarion?

Tags: bayesian, regularization, prior, random-walk

I am working with a model that contains a large number of coefficients, arranged in an ordered vector $\beta_1, \dots, \,  \beta_N $. I have some prior knowledge that could be used to improve the estimation of the $\beta$, in particular:

1. There's autocorrelation in the vector of $\beta$, such that the
   difference between contiguous values, e.g. $\beta_i$ and $\beta_{i+1}$, is more likely to be
   'small', rather than 'large';
2. I expect most $\beta$ coefficients to be unimportant; specifically I expect only a single, relatively small (compared to $N$), cluster of contiguous coefficient to be different from zero and useful for predicting my dependent variable.

I am working in a Bayesian setting (I use Stan). My idea was to include both these information in the model using a combination of a random-walk prior (to enforce smoothness and correlation between contiguous $\beta$) with a regularizing prior, to give higher prior probability to small values of $\beta$.

More in detail, I have a random walk prior such that 
$$
\beta_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1), \quad \beta_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta_{i-1}, \tau)
$$ 
where $\tau$ is a smoothness hyperparameter.

At the same time I want to penalize large values of $\beta$. In ridge regression this would be achieved by adding a penalty $-\lambda \sum_{i=1}^N \beta_i^2$ to the log-likelihood. In a Bayesian setting this should be equivalent to setting a zero-centred Gaussian prior, e.g.
$$
\beta_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)
$$

Putting everything together, this would give the following modified/regularized random walk prior:
$$
\beta_1 \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \: \frac{1}{1+2\lambda}\right), \quad \beta_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2\lambda}}{\tau + \frac{1}{2\lambda}}\beta_{i-1}, \: \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\tau} + 2\lambda} \right)
$$

**My question is**: does this approach makes sense or are there shortcomings/limitations that I have missed? Is there any reference I can cite that used similar approach? Or alternatively, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you familiar with the fused lasso? Would those ideas be helpful?

Comment: I think you’re on the right track but would use something else for the actual prior. See here for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.06908.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the fused lasso (and Bayesian fused lasso mentioned in the link), I will look into it.

Comment: i don't understand why you don't set $\beta_1 \sim N(0,\tau_1)$  and $\beta_i \sim N(\beta_{i-1},\tau)$.  your initial setup is already regularising. remember that you can pull the $\beta_{i-1}$ out of the mean. so $\beta_i= \beta_1 + \sum_{1<j<=i} N(0,\tau)$. ie you are regularising beta 1 - and the consecutive diffs.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the horseshoe-type markov random fields (MRFs) described in https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1487905413. They generalize Gaussian MRFs to include horseshoe-type priors which induce the type of shrinkage of the coefficients you want, while maintaining the autoregressive properties from a random walk. They also have a Stan implementation!